# Ubuntu LXDE: window not scrolling down?

Tags: .desktop, lxde

I've a problem with my window manager. I've opened a application, but the `[cancel] [save]` buttons, which are supposed to be at the bottom of window, are below my screen resolution and I cannot drag it up or scroll the contents down.

**PS**: I can't resize the window as well. And its an extension of burpsuite incase you want to know what application it is :)

How can I fix this issue?

**System Detail**:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

DESKTOP ENVIRONMENT: LXDE
WINDOW MANAGER: Openbox
```

**Visually**:

```
__________________________________
|  ========================-ox    |
|  |                         |    |<---- my monitor
|  |                         |    |
|  |                         |<---+------ the window
|  |                         |    |
|  |                         |    |
|__|_________________________|____|
   |                         |
   |__________[save][cancel]_|
```

Comment: You are a little short on detail, what release?  what WM are you using?  What specifically do you mean by desktop manager?  (the LXDE session manager? `pcmanfm` which handles the desktop? or something else? but release details would be a start)

Comment: @guiverc. I hope these details will help you

Comment: On Lubuntu I'd suggest right-clicking the application on the `lxpanel` and click *Maximize* and expect it to re-draw the window and have it thus fit the dimenions of your monitor so everything is visible. On modern Lubuntu there is also a *move* feature that allows you to move the window, but that wasn't available in *bionic*/LXDE  (or you could also try Super+arrow etc to move windows as per Lubuntu shortcuts)

Comment: @guiverc The `Maximize` is disabled. But that `super` thing worked man. Thank you superman. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Lubuntu I'd suggest right-clicking the application on the `lxpanel` and click *Maximize* and expect it to re-draw the window and have it thus fit the dimensions of your monitor so everything is visible.

On modern Lubuntu (using LXQt) there is also a *move* feature that allows you to move the window, but that wasn't available in *bionic* / LXDE

If that fails, I'd suggest a Lubuntu shortcut, ie. you could also try <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> etc to move windows as per Lubuntu shortcuts, which for LXDE can currently be seen at

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Keyboard

---

*Please note:*

*The wiki page will be moved (thus link will fail) when Lubuntu 18.04 LTS reaches EOL at the end of this month ; it's expected you'll need to replace Lubuntu in the link/url with LXDE*.

*The modern Lubuntu shortcut page can be found at https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/F/keyboard_shortcuts.html but not all Lubuntu/LXQt and Lubuntu/LXDE shortcuts are identical*

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/lubuntu-LXDE/Keyboard is the correct link after EOL move